# How to create a symbolic link to images in Visual Studio 2017 with ASP.NET Core project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a project that is written using `C#` on the top of ASP.NET Core 2.2 framework.

I have asset images located in a folder outside of my project that I need to make accessible to the outside world. My images are physically located at `c:/public_assets/photos`. When my app is running the URI `https://mydomain/public/any_image.jpg` would need to show the image found at `c:/public_assets/photos/any_image.jpg`.

Then I would render my pictures using razor-view like so

```
<img src="~/public/any_image.jpg" alt="..." />
```

I am hoping this would be a setting to add to the projects config file so when I deploy the project to production I would just change the configs.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new Controller

```
public class publicController : Controller
{
     public FileResult pic(string id)
    {
        var fileName = id;
        if (fileName.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) >= 0) throw new Exception();
        string absolutePath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine("c:/public_assets/photos/", fileName));
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(absolutePath)) throw new Exception();
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(absolutePath);
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(absolutePath).Replace(".", "");
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(absolutePath);
        return File(fileBytes, "image/" + fileExtension, fileName);
    }
}
```

Edit

- retrun NotFound
- don't read the file to the memory
- check for allwoed file extension

  ```
  public class publicController : Controller
  {
      public ActionResult pic(string id)
      {
          var fileName = id;
          if (fileName.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) >= 0) return NotFound();
          string absolutePath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine("c:/public_assets/photos/", fileName));
          if (!System.IO.File.Exists(absolutePath)) return NotFound();
          string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(absolutePath).Replace(".", "").ToLower();
          if (fileExtension != "jpg") return NotFound();
          var fileBytes = System.IO.File.OpenRead(absolutePath);
          fileName = Path.GetFileName(absolutePath);
          return File(fileBytes, "image/" + fileExtension, fileName);
      }
  }
  ```

then call

```
  http://xxxxxxxxx/public/pic/1.jpg

  http://xxxxxxxxx/public/pic/MikeA.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FileServer` extension method, Add the flowing code to `Configuration` method of your `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup {

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
        // other configure code
        var opts = new FileServerOptions {
            RequestPath = "/public",
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"c:/public_assets/photos")
        };
        app.UseFileServer(opts);
    }

}
```

Then you can use the image urls like this in razor pages:

```
<img src="~/public/any_image.jpg" alt="..." />
```

You can also put the two path strings into `appSettings.json`, and read them from configuration.

Comment: This seems to be a nice of doing. But I am unable to render the images. How would I generate my asset url? `~/public/any_image.jpg` is not working

Comment: Yes, just use `~/public/any_image.jpg` in razor pages.